# JavaFX: ghost area in tableview

Tags: java, javafx

Why when I clicked in ghost area of table view, I get an error. I not using constrained policy because I need to binding the width of the column with the width of tableview that  not working when cinstrained policy was set:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564938/javafx-tableview-binding-not-working-with-constrained-resize-policy

Btw I using Windows OS and NVIDIA GPU.

[image]

This is my code that I get from javaFX official example.

```
package fjr.test;
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 2012 Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
 */
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 * A simple table with a header row.
 *
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableCell
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableColumn
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TablePosition
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableRow
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableView
 */
public class TableSample extends Application {
    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob",     "Smith",    "jacob.smith@example.com" ),
            new Person("Isabella",  "Johnson",  "isabella.johnson@example.com" ),
            new Person("Ethan",     "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com" ),
            new Person("Emma",      "Jones",    "emma.jones@example.com" ),
            new Person("Michael",   "Brown",    "michael.brown@example.com" )
        );

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn();
        firstNameCol.setText("First");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn();
        lastNameCol.setText("Last");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));
        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn();
        emailCol.setText("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("email"));
        TableView tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.setItems(data);
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);
        root.getChildren().add(tableView);
    }

    public static class Person {
        private StringProperty firstName;
        private StringProperty lastName;
        private StringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() { return firstName; }
        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() { return lastName; }
        public StringProperty emailProperty() { return email; }
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

And the stack trace was:

```
run:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.handleSelectedCellsListChangeEvent(TableView.java:2657)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:2180)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:2140)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableRowBehavior.doSelect(TableRowBehavior.java:196)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableRowBehavior.mousePressed(TableRowBehavior.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in javaFX tableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553413/error-in-javafx-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to bind pref width which is null. so solution is

```
 tabel.prefWidthProperty().bind(stack.widthProperty());
nameColumn.prefWidthProperty().bind(tabel.widthProperty().multiply(0.7));
stateColumn.prefWidthProperty().bind(tabel.widthProperty().multiply(0.3));
```

you only needs to bind width property not pref width property because it can be left null of zero.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553413/error-in-javafx-tableview) and is probably a bug:

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35338